# Given a 2D array int[][], what does it mean to create a pointer int(*)[]?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, syntax

I have a question about a pointer to 2d array. If an array is something like

```
int a[2][3];
```

then, is this a pointer to array `a`?

```
int (*p)[3] = a;
```

If this is correct, I am wondering what does `[3]` mean from `int(*p)[3]`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Rather than referring to `int[2][3]` as a '2d array', you should consider it to be an 'array of arrays'. It is an array with two items in it, where each item is itself an array with 3 ints in it.

```
int (*p)[3] = a;
```

You can use `p` to point to either of the two items in `a`. `p` points to a three-int array--namely, the first such item. `p+1` would point to the second three-int array. To initialize `p` to point to the second element, use:

```
int (*p)[3] = &(a[1]);
```

The following are equivalent ways to point to the first of the two items.

```
int (*p)[3] = a; // as before
int (*p)[3] = &(a[0]);
```

Comment: You could even write  `[3]a` for example :) It's a good way of learning what arrays in C really are.

Comment: How much memory does this declaration take: `int (*p)[65];`?? Is this one pointer, or 65 pointers?

Answer (score 43):

```
int a[2][3];
```

`a` is read as an array 2 of array 3 of int which is simply an array of arrays. When you write,

`int (*p)[3] = a;`

It declares `p` as a pointer to the first element which is an *array*. So, `p` points to the array of 3 ints which is a element of array of arrays.

Consider this example:

```
        int a[2][3]
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
\_____________/
       |
       |    
       |
       p    int (*p)[3]
```

Here, `p` is your pointer which points to the array of 3 ints which is an element of array of arrays.

Comment: wouldn't "p" become an array of 3 integer pointers, with the first value pointing to the first value of "a"?

Answer (score 12):

Stricly speaking, no, `int (*p)[3] = a;` is not a pointer to `a`. It is a pointer to the first element of `a`. The first element of `a` is an array of three ints. `p` is a pointer to an array of three ints.

A pointer to the array `a` would be declared thus:

```
int (*q)[2][3] = &a;
```

The numeric value of `p` and `q` are likely (or maybe even required to be) the same, but they are of different types. This will come into play when you perform arithmetic on `p` or `q`. `p+1` points to the second element of array `a`, while `q+1` points to the memory just beyond the end of array `a`.

Remember: [cdecl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cdecl) is your friend: [`int a[2][3]`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+a%5B2%5D%5B3%5D), [`int (*q)[2][3]`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28%2aq%29%5B2%5D%5B3%5D).

Answer (score 6):

The `[3]` is a part of the type. In this case `p` is a pointer to an array of size 3 which holds ints.

The particular type of an array always includes its size, so that you have the types `int *[3]` or `int *[5]`, but not just `int *[]` which has undefined size.

```
int *x[20]; /* type of x is int *[20], not just int *[] */
int y[10][10]; /* type of y is int[10][10], not just int[][] */
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When you say size, does it mean (*p) has [0],[1]],[2] ? If this is the case, where is a room for [2]? Or does it points to [0][0] and [0][1]?

Comment: `p` is simply a pointer to an array of 3 ints. It doesn't know that the first dimension of `a` is 2, because it is assigned to the first element of `a`, which is exactly of type `int[3]`.

Answer (score 3):

Also note:

```
int *p[5]        // p is an array of 5 pointers

int (*p)[5]      // p points to an array of 5 ints

int (*(p+5))[10] // p is a pointer to a structure where the structure's 5th element has 10 ints .
```

Comment: The OP asks a conceptual question and I have answered it here. In place of 5 put 3!. Also I have added more details on how to obtain value from 2d arrays using pointers.

Comment: I would argue that this is more confusing than the rest of the answers provided here.

Answer (score 3):

you can point to 2d array like 1d array

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   int array[2][2] = {{0,1}, {2,3}}; // array
   int *ptr;
   ptr=(int*)array;
   std::cout << *(ptr)   << '\n';//out 0
   std::cout << *(ptr+1) << '\n';//out 1 
   std::cout << *(ptr+2) << '\n';//out 2
   std::cout << *(ptr+3) << '\n';//out 3
}
```