# A weird segmentation fault error

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a stack overflow exception when declaring a large array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array)

My system is `x86-64 linux` and here is my simple code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 1024
int main()
{
    int a[N][N];
    int b[N][N];
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And its assembly code from objdump:

```
00000000004004fc <main>:

4004fc: 55                      push   %rbp
4004fd: 48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
400500: 48 81 ec 00 00 80 00    sub    $0x800000,%rsp
400507: bf c4 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005c4,%edi
40050c: e8 cf fe ff ff          callq  4003e0 <puts@plt>
400511: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
400516: c9                      leaveq 
400517: c3                      retq   
400518: 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
40051f: 00
```

The weird thing is this program will break down when calling `printf()` function. However, if I define N to be 512, this program works well. I have no idea why. Is there any stack size limitation which limits the memory use by stack?

Does anybody know why? Thanks.

Comment: Somewhat ironic to ask this on StackOverflow

Comment: What's the output of `ulimit -s`?

Comment: How about putting definition of `a` and `b` *outside*?

Comment: Weired Seg fault? No. This is the way it should be...

Comment: Nemo, I get it. It is ironic to ask this on StackOverflow. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Error due to exceeding stack size. To get rid of this create the arrays in heap. To do that use `malloc` or other dynamic memory allocation functions.

Like 
     `int *a = malloc(N*N*sizeof(int))` this way memory is located in heap. 

Also you should test if this memory has been allocated for you by checking:

```
if(a)
     // do stuff with a
```

Comment: [Do not cast the return of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/)

Comment: And there is no `new` in C.

Comment: Edited accordingly. thanks for the reminder @ThiefMaster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a maximum stack size which is small, most of the times smaller than a few `KBs`. You are trying to allocate `1024*1024*sizeof(int)=4194304bytes` or `4MBs` of data into a single stack allocation which results in a crash.

There are 2 ways to counter this:

1) Allocate the memory outside of the stack

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 1024

int a[N][N];
int b[N][N];    

int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

or 2) dynamically allocate memory from the heap inside `main()` using `malloc()`:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define N 1024

    int main()
    {
        int **a = malloc(N, sizeof(int*));
        int **b = malloc(N, sizeof(int*));
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
          a[i]=malloc(N, sizeof(int));
          b[i]=malloc(N, sizeof(int));
         }
        printf("hello world\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

**Note**: Do not forget to `free()` any dynamically allocated memory after you are done with the data it holds, otherwise your program will leak memory.

Comment: `int **` is very wrong here.

Comment: @Nemo explain why please

Comment: Well, it was very wrong before you made your edit :-).  `a` and `b` in the original code decay to `int *`, not `int **`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is limit on how much you can allocate on stack at a given time. It is compiler dependent. On visual studio default size is 1 MB. Check your compiler settings to know the size. My guess is since you are exceeding this limit it is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I might as well give my answer, borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617466/):

```
int (*a)[N] = malloc(N * N * sizeof(int));
int (*b)[N] = malloc(N * N * sizeof(int));
```

Now you can access them like the 2D arrays in your original code; e.g. `a[50][100] = 37;`

Do not forget to `free(a)` and `free(b)` when you are done with them.