# Boost multiarray 3D

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I am using a boost mutli array for 2D as follows,

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> array_type;
    typedef array_type::index index;
    // initialize array
    array_type U(boost::extents[N][3]);
    for(index i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        for(index j = 0; j != 3; ++j){
            U[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    double * pU = U.data();
    double (*arrayU)[3] = (double (*)[3])pU;
```

Now I am trying to implement it but for 3D, so far I have written the following,

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
    typedef array_type::index index;
    // initialize array
    array_type U(boost::extents[M][N][4]);
    for(index i = 0; i != M; ++i) {
        for(index j = 0; j != N; ++j){
            for(index k = 0; k != 4; ++k){
            U[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

But the following part is still confusing for me, can you please tell me how to do it and explain it a little bit?

```
    double * pU = U.data();
    double (*arrayU)[3] = (double (*)[3])pU;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multi_array<T>.data()` returns a pointer to the beginning of the contiguous block, then cast the pointer to a pointer of the array of 3 doubles which is an element of array of arrays. Take a look at this link: [A pointer to 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617466/a-pointer-to-2d-array)
**EDIT:**
It's the same for 3D array, for example, you write this for 3D array:

```
double * pU = U.data();
double (*arrayU)[N][4] = (double (*)[N][4])pU;
```

You have declared `arrayU` to be a pointer to a N * 4 matrix of double, that is, it points to an array of N arrays of 4 doubles. Given this, `arrayU[0]` is an array of N arrays of 4 doubles. However, since it is an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: still dont get it that clearly, then for a 3D array I should write: double * pU = U.data(); double (arrayU)[N][4] = (double ()[N][4])pU;