# C++ Pointers with 2D Arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

How do you you implement function that takes a pointer `int*` to a 2D array as an input? My current code is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void){
  int M [4][4] = {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {9,10,11,12},
    {13,14,15,16},
  };
  int* Mat = M;
  myFunc(Mat);
}

void myFunc(int* Matrix)
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617466/a-pointer-to-2d-array

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I, too, cannot tell what you are asking. A question typically contains a question mark.

Comment: "I am currently working on a C++ function that I am working on" is probably this month's best.

Comment: You must have been given some description of what the argument is supposed to be. (My guess is that you're expected to store your data in a one-dimensional array and compute the one-dimensional index from the two-dimensional ones.)

Comment: You can't pass `M` as `int*`, you can pass a row of `M`, but not the entire `M`.

Answer (score 1):

MxN arrays decay to a pointer to the first row (length N). If you want a pointer to the beginning then you need to allow the first row to decay to a pointer to the first element. Also note what @Pete Becker says below.

```
#include <iostream>

void myFunc(int* Matrix);

int main (void){
  int M [4][4] = {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {9,10,11,12},
    {13,14,15,16},
  };

  int* Mat = M[0];
  myFunc(Mat);
}
```

Comment: **Two** dimensional arrays decay to a pointer to the first row. **Thee** dime signal arrays decay to a pointer to the first two dimensional array. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple and it only took me like 4 hours (gotta love coding).
So take out `int* Mat = M[0];` and when calling the function simply recast as `(int*)`

```css
#include <iostream>

void myFunc(int* Matrix);

int main (void){
  int M [4][4] = {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {9,10,11,12},
    {13,14,15,16},
  };

  myFunc((int*)M);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

M pointing to the first row, but its value is the same as pointer to the first element which is M[0][0], so you might change the interpretation for compiler:

```
int* Mat = reinterpret_cast<int*>(M);
```

Comment: The type of `M` is `int[4][4]`

Comment: that's not true, do you define a variable like this `int p[4][4] = M;`? this won't even compile.

Comment: It is true, the C standard says so.  The reason `int p[4][4] = M;` does not compile is that array initializers must be a braced list of initializers for each element